# how to do a certain thing in a loop, every odd iteration

Tags: javascript, loops

[image]so I have the following problem(on the picture) and above is what I've tried so far. So basicly I don't know the proper way to make a certain thing if the iteration index is an odd number, I tried some things but they dont seen to be working.

```
const journey = arr =>{
  let cost = Number(arr[0]);
  let months = Number(arr[1]);
  let currentMoney = 0;
  let suveniri = cost - currentMoney;
  for(let i = 0; i < months; i++){
     currentMoney += cost * 0.25;
     if(i > 1 && i % 3 == 0){
       currentMoney * 0.84;
     }
     if (i && (i % 4 === 0)){
        currentMoney * 1.25;
     }
  }
  if(suveniri < 0){
        console.log(`Bravo! You can go to Disneyland and you will have ${suveniri}lv. for souvenirs.`)
     }
     else if(suveniri > 0){
      console.log(`Sorry. You need ${suveniri}lv. more.`);
     }
 }
journey([ '1000', '4' ]);
```

Comment: Just... `i%2 == 1`, it's not voodoo magic. You *do* need to assign the result of `currentMoney * (1-0.16)` to something though.

Answer (score 2):

An even number should be divisible by `2` without a remainder and a whole number as a result.

```
i % 2 === 0 // Even.
```

And an odd number, well, is not an even number. So checking if a number is not even will do the trick.

```
i % 2 !== 0 // Odd.
```

Every other iteration, like every fourth, can be determined in the same way, by checking if the remainder is `0`.

Because you're using it in a loop, you start counting a `0` and the fourth iteration will have the index at the value `3`. So that changes the logic. Add `1` to each index to start counting from `1`, which will solve the offset.

```
(i + 1) % 4 === 0 // Every fourth.
```

Comment: What about every fourth iteration to do something ?

Comment: use i%4 === 0 for fouth month